# how to delete completely a programm app from Ubuntu 20.04, in this case Lollypop

Tags: delete, software-uninstall

When trying to uninstall Lollypop program/app from my device using Ubuntu 20.04, I use purge and autoremove. But when installing it again, the programa is up in the same place where it was before the uninstallation.
Is any way that I can completely get reed of the cache and data of that program/app so I can do a clean installation again??

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to manually remove the cached files located in `~/.cache/lollypop`. When in doubt about persistent settings, check your home directory.

Ideal complete removal process:

1. Remove the application:
   `apt remove --purge lollypop`
2. Open Terminal, make sure you're in the home directory:
   `cd ~`
3. Look for `lollypop` directories
4. Remove the cache:
   `cd ~/.cache`
   `rm -Rf lollypop`
5. Look for other `lollypop` directories in `~/.cache`
6. Re-install

---

If you *still* have files from Lollypop (or any other application), then you'll need to be a bit more creative and use the `find` command to suss them out.

First look for directories:

```
find . -type d -name 'lolly*'
```

This will search the current directory *and all subdirectories* for any directory name starting with "lolly". If you see anything in the output, you will need to empty the directories and delete them. If you would like to check the entire file system, use `find /` instead of `find .`. Be advised that this can take a while depending on how many files and folders you have.

Once the directories are done, look for any additional files that may exist in common locations:

```
find . -type f -name 'lolly*.*'
```

This, too, will search the current directory *and all subdirectories* for any file name starting with "lolly". If you see anything in the output, you will need to delete them. If they can all be deleted, you can save time by doing this:

```
find . -type f -name 'lolly*.*' -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Be 100% sure *before you use this command* that all files starting with "lolly" can be deleted, as **there is no undo**.

If there are *still* files after this, get in touch with the Lollypop developers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your easy explanation.

Comment: I still have things from Lollypop in my computer after doing this. Can you write exactly what I have to write in the Terminal??

Comment: I've updated the answer. Hopefully this will give you what you need. If it does not, be sure to reach out to the Lollypop developers (nicely) to ask where they store files on your computer.

Comment: pom. Thanks a lot. I just have another question. how can I delete them? I might use something like disk usage analyzer?

Comment: If you are trying to delete a directory and everything inside them, you will need to use `rm -Rf`. However, **be careful** when issuing this command as there is no undo. So, if you want to delete `~/whatever` and everything inside the directory, you will use `rm -Rf ~/whatever`. If there are files owned by other users, you may need to put `sudo` in front of `rm`. Again, **be careful** when using this command as there is no confirmation, and **there is no undo**.

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: find . -type d -name 'rhythmbox*'
./.local/share/rhythmbox
./.var/app/org.gnome.Rhythmbox3/data/rhythmbox
./.var/app/org.gnome.Rhythmbox3/cache/rhythmbox

I got these, but sorry, I cant find that files. where I should look after them?? I havent learn this yet . I feel so stupid right now